# Makefile with multiple targets

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

Hopefully this is a very simple question. I have a makefile pattern rule that looks like this:

```
%.so : %.f %.pyf
    f2py -c -L${LAPACK_DIR} ${GRASPLIBS} -m $* $^ ${SOURCES} --opt='-02' --f77flags='-fcray-pointer' >> silent.txt
```

I want the makefile to build a number of .so files, so I tried to get it to build two files (radgrd_py.so and lodiso_py.so) by doing this:

```
radgrd_py.so lodiso_py.so:

%.so : %.f %.pyf
f2py -c -L${LAPACK_DIR} ${GRASPLIBS} -m $* $^ ${SOURCES} --opt='-02' --f77flags='-fcray-pointer' >> silent.txt
```

and then tried this:

```
radgrd_py.so:

lodiso_py.so:

%.so : %.f %.pyf
f2py -c -L${LAPACK_DIR} ${GRASPLIBS} -m $* $^ ${SOURCES} --opt='-02' --f77flags='-fcray-pointer' >> silent.txt
```

But in each case, it only builds the first target that I specify. If I run 'make radgrd_py.so' it works fine, I'm just not sure how to specify a list of files that need to be built so I can just run 'make'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The usual trick is to add a 'dummy' target as the first that depends on all targets you want to build when running a plain `make`:

```
all: radgrd_py.so lodiso_py.so
```

It is a convention to call this target 'all' or 'default'. For extra correctness, let `make` know that this is not a real file by adding this line to your `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to add:

```
.PHONY: all
.DEFAULT: all
all: radgrd_py.so lodiso_py.so
```

Explanations:

*make* uses the first target appearing when no `.DEFAULT` is specified.

`.PHONY` informs *make* that the targets (a coma-separated list, in fact) don't create any file or folder.

`all:` as proposed by *schot*