# can single gcc generate executable for multiple targets like x86,arm,ppc?

Tags: gcc, arm, powerpc

We want to use a single gcc for multiple targets. Is it possible to build from source for supporting multiple targets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile with multiple targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519610/makefile-with-multiple-targets)

Comment: What exactly are you calling "a single gcc" and why having one is desired?

Comment: No gcc is not designed that way, you are welcome to re-write it, about  a third to half would need to be replaced, and/or just make a generic backend from which then your backend has a switch to hit multiple targets.

Comment: Making this possible is a (very) long time goal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot do this with `gcc`. You can use some cross compilers to achieve this goal.

But if you really need to do this, you can use `clang` compiler. Here is the link:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer to the Gabriel. All architecture what you mentioned above are different CPU's.

It's not possible to generate different binaries with the gcc compiler. 
You need to have different toolchains for each compiler that produce corresponding compatible code.

x86, PPC and ARM are the different machines. You cant run the code which you build using host toolchains.

---

Below provided reference use machine specific toolchains not host-gcc. This is very cumbersome and not straightforward approach.

For curiosity, you can have a look at the `bitbake`, [parallel build of multiple machines](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-December/022676.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'll also add that to have a useful toolchain you also need to build other components besides GCC. Components like an assembler and linker (from binutils for example) and a C library (e.g. glibc, musl, newlib etc). Each such component needs to be configured for a specific target